# Visual Studio 2013 Git Extensions and GitHub Private Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013

If I try to Pull/Push from within Visual Studio I get the following error:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

I can do everything from the command line though but the following message always gets printed:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe" store: C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe: No such file or directory
```

Not to mention that there is not `GitExtensions` directory in my `Program Files`.
Any solution is appreciated there is very little on the web regarding Visual Studio Git extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default windows stores the passwords in passwords vault, by using credentials manager we can update the passwords of saved password of web and windows applications.

Open Credentials Manager > Locate Github account either on windows account or web account and update password.

By deleting github details by above steps Visual studio will prompt password when clone or push.